# I want to pass the email to another screen after login by using React-native authentication flows

Tags: react-native

Pls give me a hand, I just want to pass the email to another screen after login, I only know to do it like this, but when it comes to authentication flows I don't know how to do it :  <Button   title="Login" onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Login', {email: 'myemail@gmail.com', }); }}  />

I am kindly using this reference : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/
I just need a hand from here:

```
  const authContext = React.useMemo(
() => ({
  signIn: async (data) => {
  

    dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
  },
  signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
  signUp: async (data) => {
    // In a production app, we need to send user data to server and get a token
    // We will also need to handle errors if sign up failed
    // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `SecureStore` or any other encrypted storage
    // In the example, we'll use a dummy token

    dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
  },
}),
[]
```

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the below answers you questions since you only want to share data between screens.  Easiest way to do so is to pass parameters to routes - see example below and link for more information.

Example below passes the email state to the HomeScreen on successful auth.

Refer to the link to see how to receive that email on the Home screen.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

**login.js**

```
    signIn = async () => {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

  // This may differ to whatever auth service you are using
  await Auth.signIn(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then((user) => {

  // if successful and credentials valid
       navigate('Home', { email: this.state.email])

     }
 }
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Login"
      component={LoginScreen}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: No problem.  If the answer solved your question, please mark it as correct. Just so others will know this has been solved.  Thank you.